# Creating entangled electron pairs using Stern-Gerlach apparatus?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement, spinors

The following is a drawing of the sequential Stern Gerlach experiment.

[image]

As we can detect the fraction of the electrons passing through each magnet, I suppose it is possible to detect how many electrons have passed through a Stern-Gerlach apparatus without *ending/blocking* the electron's path (ie. allowing each electron to continue its journey further along the setup)?

Suppose that we have 2 electrons, on which we would like to test their Z-axis spin. If we detect that one electron (don't know which) is deflected **UP** by the magnetic field, and the other electron (don't know which) is deflected **DOWN** by the magnetic field, this means that we have now ascertained that our two electrons have **opposite** spins.

My question is: *does this weak measurement collapse the superposition states of these 2 electrons*, meaning electron A will definitely measure an **UP** spin from now on and electron B will definitely measure a **DOWN** spin from now on (or vice verca), or are their respective spin states still in superposition, thus electron A can still measure either **UP** or **DOWN** at any later time, with electron B always matching electron A's opposite spin?

In the latter case, then haven't we successfully **entangled** electron A with electron B, which were not previously entangled before?

Comment: *"Suppose that we have 2 electrons, on which we would like to test their Z-axis spin. If we detect that one electron (don't know which) is deflected UP by the magnetic field, and the other electron (don't know which) is deflected DOWN by the magnetic field, this means that we have now ascertained that our two electrons have opposite spins."* how would you know that exactly one of the two electrons is deflected up/down without measuring them?

Comment: @ACuriousMind thank you. that's the firstmost question i asked, because from the standard sequential stern-gerlach apparatus shown above, how would we get 50%, 25% following each filter, while still allowing the electrons to pass on unobstructed to the next filter. Then I speculated whether this is a form of weak measurement which may not completely collapse the superposition states of the electron?

Comment: I don't really understand your comment. The percentages here are just the frequencies in the limit of infinitely many electrons. If you send $n$ electrons in, it is perfectly possible, though improbable as $2^{-n}$, that you'll measure all $n$ in one particular branch at the end. There is no guarantee that either of them will end up in any particular branch. Also: [Weak measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_measurement) is a technical term that means something completely different.

Comment: @ACuriousMind apologies for using the wrong term. I meant by "weak measurement" in reference to ones used in quantum teleportation to measure a vague enough system state so that the superposition state of the electron spins is not collapsed altogether. What methods are used to perform those type of "weak/incomplete measurement" of a quantum system's state in order to preserve some of its superposition?

Comment: The fact that two particles come out with different measurements does not imply they are correlated or entangled in any way.

Comment: @JonCuster Suppose the two particles come out of the Stern-Gerlach magnetic field with opposite spins. Would this "oppositeness" be maintained for any later time, meaning that whenever these two particles are later measured, their spins will still be opposite to each other always?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Correlation means IF we measure A in state up, THEN B must necessarily be in state down, and vice-versa.  It can only apply to admixed states.  Once a pure state has been achieved, correlation is broken (in theory anyway).  In the situation envisioned (eg, only 1 type of filter, but on different paths), A will always be up post initial measurement and B will always be down.  That is, A and B are already in pure states and even if correlation once existed (though in the standard set-up it did not), it doesn't anymore.

NB:  Technically the spin decoheres over time so it's not quite true that A will always be measured up for all time, but assuming the experiment is carried out over a reasonably short time, it will be.

Now we COULD take additional steps to correlate them post initial measurement, per James' answer, but that's a different question.

Answer (score -2):

Creating entangled particles are straightforward at the circuit level.

[image]

Starting from two particles with known |0> spin, a Hadamard gate followed by a CNOT gate will put both bits into an equal superposition states as well as *entangle* the two bits's outcome, because:

[image]